# How do i know if there is some syntax in javascript or html doesn't works in some browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

the question as you all know, its for the IE :), because as usual, it doesn't follow the standards in some times. So, I need to know before I write some code, I need to know if its supported in the other browser or not. and the one that I need to check for it as usual is IE, because chrome & firefox most of the times they worked the same & gives a great result, while in IE it gives a rubbish & some wired stuff.

So, I need a site that can tells me for JS,jQuery,Html & Css which syntax that its not working in other browser & in a specific versions.

Also, is there is a way to test the code on different browser(and versions) without needing to install them all on the computer ??

Thanks alot...

Comment: Just for the record, one of the best points of jQuery is that it handles most of cross-browsers stuff. So if you're just about jQuery, don't worry about this. About CSS, though... see the answers :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest 
http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html (css2.1 and javascript) 
http://findmebyip.com/litmus and http://caniuse.com/ (for css3 and html5)

besides there is also 
http://www.positioniseverything.net/
for an explanation of most common bugs on old IE versions

Answer (score 1):

I use http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html as a basis for checkign whether a specific css syntax is supported in a particular browser, or if there is a css issue i can't seem to solve, i'll look here.

also, microsoft do have virtual images XP IE6, XP IE7, etc that get updated every couple of months, that web developers can download to test their sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can use websites like http://www.browserstack.com/ or http://browserling.com/ for cross-browser testing. [Testling](http://testling.com/) is also a good fit for this.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/ has compatibility tables for CSS, JS, and HTML.

jQuery is normalized to work pretty much the same everywhere.

Comment: Given the reputation of that site, I thought I'd test a couple of things to see if it was any good at covering compatibility issues. Shame that its description of `getElementById` is dubious, that it doesn't mention the bugs that method has in IE, and that it doesn't appear to cover `getElementsByClassName` at all. [W3Schools is best avoided](http://w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 0):

For CSS compatibility issues you can also check out modernizr.js (http://www.modernizr.com/).  It's pretty slick and allows you to use feature detection for browsers, as opposed to checking for client version.  That and JQuery can really reduce bug/hack insanity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look into Selenium testing. There are some sites where you can run these tests online, for example http://testingbot.com